# Spring Cache Eviction

Tags: spring, caching, spring-4, spring-cache

I have two services

```
class CustomerService {
   public void removeCustomer(int customerId) {...}
}

class OrderService {
   @Cacheable("orders")
   public List<Order> getOrders() {...}
}
```

On `removeCustomer()` I want the `orders` cache to be evicted, since the result has changed (the orders of the removed customers are gone). How can I do this with Spring's caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @CacheEvict annotation for the same. Please refer to the below link for details

[https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CacheEvict.html](http://Spring%20Framework%20Documentation%20reference)

You can find example at

https://dzone.com/articles/spring-31-caching-and-0